# Cannot read property 'number' of undefined ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component in which I have form that needs to be filled. I want to pass values such as city, name and number. But when I try to sumbit form with number filled I get an error. Everything works fine with only adding two first inputs, but the problem is in the last one.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StationService from '../services/StationService';

class CreateStationComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            station: {
                id: this.props.match.params.id,
                city: '',
                name: '',
                trains: [
                    {
                        number: '',
                        numberOfCarriages: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

        this.changeCityHandles = this.changeCityHandles.bind(this);
        this.changeNameHandles = this.changeNameHandles.bind(this);
        this.saveStation = this.saveStation.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (this.state.station.id === '_add') {
            return;
        } else {
            StationService.getStationById(this.state.station.id).then((res) => {
                let station = res.data;
                this.setState({ name: station.name, city: station.city })
            });
        }
    }

    changeCityHandles = (event) => {
        this.setState({ city: event.target.value });
    }

    changeNameHandles = (event) => {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }

    changeNumberHandles = (event) => {
        this.setState({ number: event.target.value });
    }

    saveStation = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let station = { city: this.state.city, name: this.state.name, number: this.state.trains.number }

        if (this.state.station.id === '_add') {
            StationService.createStation(station).then(res => {
                this.props.history.push('/stations');
            });
        } else {
            StationService.updateStation(station, this.state.station.id).then(res => {
                this.props.history.push('/stations');
            });
        }
    }

    cancel() {
        this.props.history.push('/stations');
    }

    getTitle() {
        if (this.state.id === '_add') {
            return <h3 className="text-center">Dodaj stację</h3>
        } else {
            return <h3 className="text-center">Modyfikuj stację</h3>
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                            {
                                this.getTitle()
                            }
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label>Miejscowość</label>
                                        <input placeholder="Miejscowość" name="city" className="form-control" value={this.state.city} onChange={this.changeCityHandles} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label>Nazwa stacji</label>
                                        <input placeholder="Nazwa stacji" name="name" className="form-control" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeNameHandles} />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label>Pociąg</label>
                                        {/* <input placeholder="Nazwa stacji" name="number" className="form-control" value={this.state.trains.map(t => t.number)} onChange={this.changeNameHandles} /> */}
                                        <input placeholder="Nazwa stacji" name="number" className="form-control" onChange={this.changeNumberHandles} />
                                    </div>

                                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.saveStation}>Zapisz</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>Odrzuć</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is in the line:

```
let station = { city: this.state.city, name: this.state.name, number: this.state.trains.number }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The same as in the title: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

Comment: Your changehandlenumber is overriding your state schema. You need to spread previous state and assign train number prop only.

Comment: The initial state doesn't match how you're using it later in the code

Comment: I don't know React so well, can you tell me how should I do this?

Comment: I added the code take a look handle function,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can change a single property in your state. here is the demo link. https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-davinci-w730t?file=/src/Sample.js:1477-1706

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StationService from "../services/StationService";

class CreateStationComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      station: {
        id: this.props.match.params.id,
        city: "",
        name: "",
        trains: [
          {
            number: "",
            numberOfCarriages: ""
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    this.changeCityHandles = this.changeCityHandles.bind(this);
    this.changeNameHandles = this.changeNameHandles.bind(this);
    this.saveStation = this.saveStation.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.station.id === "_add") {
      return;
    } else {
       StationService.getStationById(this.state.station.id).then((res) => {
         let station = res.data;
         this.setState({ ...this.state,
          station:{
                ...this.state.station,
                name: station.name,
                city:station.city
                }});

       });
    }
  }

  changeCityHandles = (event) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state,
      station:{
            ...this.state.station,
            city: event.target.value
            }});
  };

  changeNameHandles = (event) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state,
      station:{
            ...this.state.station,
            name: event.target.value
            }});
  };

 
changeNumberHandles = (event) => {
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  station:{
      ...this.state.station,
    trains: {
    ...this.state.trains,
    number: event.target.value
  }
}});
};

  saveStation = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let station = {
      city: this.state.city,
      name: this.state.name,
      number: this.state.trains.number
    };

    if (this.state.station.id === "_add") {
       StationService.createStation(station).then((res) => {
         this.props.history.push("/stations");
       });
    } else {
       StationService.updateStation(station, this.state.station.id).then(
         (res) => {
           this.props.history.push("/stations");
         }
       );
    }
  };

  cancel() {
    this.props.history.push("/stations");
  }

  getTitle() {
    if (this.state.id === "_add") {
      return <h3 className="text-center">Dodaj stację</h3>;
    } else {
      return <h3 className="text-center">Modyfikuj stację</h3>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
              {this.getTitle()}
              <div className="card-body">
                <form>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Miejscowość</label>
                    <input
                      placeholder="Miejscowość"
                      name="city"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={this.state.city}
                      onChange={this.changeCityHandles}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Nazwa stacji</label>
                    <input
                      placeholder="Nazwa stacji"
                      name="name"
                      className="form-control"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.changeNameHandles}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Pociąg</label>
                    {/* <input placeholder="Nazwa stacji" name="number" className="form-control" value={this.state.trains.map(t => t.number)} onChange={this.changeNameHandles} /> */}
                    <input
                      placeholder="Nazwa stacji"
                      name="number"
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={this.changeNumberHandles}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={this.saveStation}
                  >
                    Zapisz
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)}
                    style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
                  >
                    Odrzuć
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CreateStationComponent
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to do this, I get an error that state is undefined

Comment: ok, I updated to code based on your state structure, take a look again,

Comment: Thank you, that works, but values are empty and they are not properly passed to save function.

Comment: I updated the code with a small fix and added a demo link, you can check now. Check  changeNumberHandles  this time.

Comment: Thank you very much, but now submit button does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The state Trains is declared as an array. But have not mentioned the index value while using below line.

```
let station = { city: this.state.city, name: this.state.name, number: this.state.trains.number }
```

Change it to below:-

```
let station = { city: this.state.station.city, name: this.state.station.name, number: this.state.station.trains[0].number }
```